# Why $E|X-Y|^2 = 0$ implies $P(X=Y) = 1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

Why does $$\mathbb{E}|X(t)-Y(t)|^2 = 0$$ imply $$\mathbb{P}(X(t)=Y(t))=1$$
for all $t$.

**Idea:** By Markov we get $\mathbb{P}(|X-Y|^2 \geq a)=0$, respectively $\mathbb{P}(|X-Y|^2 < a)=1$ with $a$ any real number.
I believe this is a first step, but what is the following step and how is it written mathematically correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every $n \geq 1$, Markov's inequality gives
$$\mathbb{P}\left(|X-Y|^2 \geq \frac{1}{n}\right) = 0$$

So by countable union, you get $$\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{n \geq 1} \left\lbrace |X-Y|^2 \geq \frac{1}{n} \right\rbrace\right)=0$$

which is equivalent to
$$\mathbb{P}(|X-Y|^2 > 0)= 0$$

i.e.
$$\mathbb{P}(|X-Y|^2 =0)= 1$$
i.e.
$$\mathbb{P}(X=Y)= 1$$

Comment: Perfect! Thank a lot.